# Why did Ubuntu 14.04 create a 15.8GB swap partition?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, swap, partitioning

I started with Windows 7 on 120GB SSD and Ubuntu 14.04 **32bit** installed on 60GB partition on separate 1TB HDD. I just did a fresh reinstall of 14.04 **64bit** on the 1TB HDD. In the installation set up process, I selected the second choice of "deleting Ubuntu 14.04 and all it's files,documents, photos etc and reinstalling" to what I figured would reinstall the 64bit OS on the already existing 60GB allocated partition. Instead, it reinstalled Ubuntu as 43.5 GB and created a separate 15.8 partition. So now it reads that my disk space for Ubuntu ( in settings>details) is 43.5GB (instead of the previous 60GB that my old 32bit had)

The upside is I can now access my 1TB HDD from my toolbar(and all the files located on it) Before, I could only access that through Windows (I can also access the SSD too, but that was always the case) Both drives are mounted now.

My initial reaction was to go into Windows 7> disk management> delete the strange/new 15gb partition>extend the 43.5 to the unallocated space. But I'm not sure if this is necessary or would even work.
My question is why did it create a 15gb partition shrinking my ubuntu disk space, and is it useful? I don't want wasted space, so before I go through all my set up of Ubuntu, should I change this. 
At this time my HDD reads as 43.5 partiton, 15.8 partition, and 874GB exfat32 (939GB total)

So yes, per Gparted it's linux-swap. Why do I have that now? My previous set up showed disk space as complete 60 GB (technically 59.?)

[image: Gparted]

Comment: If you install and run gparted under ubuntu, it might show you exactly what the new 15.8 partition is, might be a linux swap partition or something.

Comment: Do not use Windows to modify anything but the Windows system NTFS partition. It may not correctly rewrite partition table and since it does not see Linux, you may delete the wrong thing. Use gparted but investigate what the partitions are. Post this sudo parted -l Or better still run the BootInfo report from Boot-Repair and post link. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Are you saying run "sudo parted -l" ?

Comment: Most Linux distributions including Ubuntu by default makes a swap partition that is equal to your computers memory. This is so you can keep your RAMs contents saved to disk if you ever hibernate.  It is also use as extra room in case your ram becomes full, without swap and you max out your ram your system will kill off what it considers unimportant processes. If you do not hibernate then you could get away with having a swap of a few GB like me.

Comment: Ok, I was reading up on it and it makes sense. Strange I didn't get that on previous install and it read as full 60GB. I suppose the 41.28GB is plenty of room? Especially since I have access to save files on the fat32?

Comment: I'm not sure why that boot partition is 41.28 GB, or why you are using 4 GB of said partition, especially since the boot partition should be around 100-200 MB.

Comment: It's not a boot partition. It's the root filesystem.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input. @VA6DAH started me in the right direction. I never knew about the linux-swap partition before. For whatever reason, it was not available on my last 32bit install, and I don't know if I've ever noticed it on previous machines. At any rate, upon further research, I shrank the linux swap to 2.5 and then used the unallocated towards the root.  VA6DAH, if you could turn your comment into answer, I'll mark solved. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry @Mike for taking so long, been away for awhile. Glad I helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Linux distributions by default will make a swap partition that is equal to your computers memory. This is so you can keep your RAMs contents saved to disk if you ever hibernate. It is also used as extra room in case your ram becomes full. If you max out your ram without swap your systems kernel will kill off what it considers non-critical processes. If you do not hibernate or have the feature disable then a small swap of a few gigabytes will work as a safety net.